# Static memory allocation - is it allocated sequentially?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, static-memory-allocation

I need to know if it is guaranteed, for all compilers, that `&N == &N_neg[MAXN]` in the following code.

```
int N_neg[MAXN], N[MAXN]; // defined in the global scope!
T<N> t; // so I can access N[i] (for i < 0) inside T
```

If so, I'm done, this is all I need. **If not, please read my full problem below.**

**NOTE:** This is meant for programming contests **only**, so don't worry about maintainability. I'm more concerned about keeping `T` easy to understand.

---

I have the following definition:

```
template<int* B> class T { ... }
```

Inside `T`, however, I access `B[-n]`, where `n > 0`. So, this is what I want to do:

```
#define MAXN 1000
int N[2*MAXN];
T<N + MAXN> t;
```

This is not allowed, according to the compiler. [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_parameters) even has an example of this particular case saying it **does not** work, and I have already searched everywhere else for a solution (none to be found yet). I do understand how templates work, and I do know that (and why) the value of each template argument must be known during compilation time, and the address of `N` is only known later during linking.

Any suggestions?

---

Here is the full code (just in case someone has any suggestion based on the problem):

```
template<int M, int B[]> struct Hash {
    int h; Hash(int h = 0): h(h) {}
    int disp(int i) { return B[i]; }
    Hash concat(int ch, int i) { return (h + (ll) ch * B[i]) % M; }
    Hash subtract(int hl, int i) { return (ll) (h - hl + M) * B[-i] % M; }
    static void genBase(int n, int b) {
        B[0] = 1, B[-1] = powlg(b, M-2, M); // b^(-1) % M = b^(M-2) % M
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
            B[i] = (ll) B[i-1] * b % M, B[-i] = (ll)B[-i+1] * B[-1] % M;
    }
};
```

Comment: Well, like cpreference says you can't do what you want.  You you explain what you are trying to solve with this and we can help you find a different way?

Comment: The different way I guess would be to pass MAXN to T, so I would access B[MAXN+n] instead of B[n] inside. I want to avoid that. I'm going to add the full code above anyway just in case. Thanks for your time!

Comment: I edited my question based on your answer.

Comment: Other than code obfuscation, can you explain what doing this would achieve?

Comment: This is for programming contests. It must be a (1)short (2)efficient code that is (3)easy to modify. I tried using classes and templates in the past in my trd (team reference document) and it was a disaster. The everything-in-the-global-scope ended up being WAY better to all these factors. As a software engineer, I hate this idea, so I'm trying something hybrid now. The most efficient approach is to have a single B array for all hashes. And putting as a static variable inside Hash == more code. I wanted to avoid the "MAXN+" because it was hard to understand (and adapt).

Comment: I think the only acceptable solution for me is to pass B and Bneg to Hash. I already modified my code to work that way, but I'm still hoping there is a better approach.

Comment: By the way, I used to have a 350 lines string hashing "library" written by myself inside my TRD. A huge class full of utilities to do mostly anything. At first I thought it looked awesome, since it was so easy to read and very efficient (I spent a lot of time making each method as efficient as possible). But then when I actually started needing it during contests, and I'd have to copy at least 50 lines so I could use the one method I needed, I noticed how stupid that idea was, and replaced the entire library by 8 lines of pure text with the basic math (just in case I forgot).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> if it is guaranteed, for all compilers, that `&N == &N_neg[MAXN]`

It is absolutely **not** guaranteed. The C++ standard does not mandate the relative memory layout of variables. In fact, it places very little restrictions on memory layout *in general*.

It's technically not even guaranteed that `N` and `N_neg` won't be optimized away by the compiler in some cases (though taking their addresses will generally prevent this from happening).

---

To make the layout sequential, you can use a struct:

```
struct { int N_neg[MAXN], N[MAXN]; } arrays;
```

Then, *in theory* you can access `N_neg[MAXN]` as the same memory location as `N[0]`.  However, **this is undefined behavior!** It *could* work for you, but let's say you assign to `N_neg[MAXN]`. The compiler may assume that `N[0]` couldn't've been modified, and optimize away any accesses to it, causing your program to behave strangely.

You can get around this to some degree by declaring both arrays `volatile`, but then you lose out on a ton of potential optimizations.

Therefore, I would be very reluctant to use this approach.  It's almost always better to stick to defined behavior.

---

Based on the updated/discovered requirements, this gets you *close* to needing only one template parameter:

```
template <typename T, T&>
struct Hash;

template <std::size_t Size, typename T, T (&Array)[Size]>
struct Hash<T[Size], Array>
{
    // Your code here

private:
    static constexpr T *N = &Array[Size / 2];
};
```

Instantiated like this:

```
int N_backing[MAXN * 2];
Hash<decltype(N_backing), N_backing> hash;
```

As `N` is `constexpr`, its value is guaranteed to be computed at compile time.

Comment: Okay, so from NathanOliver's answer and from your answer I'm assuming there is absolutely no way to do what I want without also having MAXN as a template parameter. Is that correct?

Comment: @user3225454 If you want them laid out sequentially, you could use a struct. Though it's technically still undefined behavior to go out of bounds on the first array into the second array -- the compiler might do weird optimization things in the face of UB.

Comment: That's genius! UB is certainly a problem though, and I had completely forgot about it. I could use volatile, but then I guess I'd be missing some nice optimizations. I decided to just use template<int M, int B[], int Bn[]> struct Hash { ... }; it doesn't make the code as clearer (B[-i] makes it clear to me it means B^-i, while Bn[i] not as much), but is still easy to read and works fine without problems.

Comment: What if I NEVER access arrays.N_neg, only arrays.N (with negative indices)?

Comment: @user3225454 It's still undefined behavior to dereference a pointer out of the array bounds. What's the reasoning for wanting two separate arrays instead of a single array?

Comment: Avoid having to add a constant MAXN to the index I'm going to access. The options are: (1) B[MAXN+idx] (2) B[idx] (3) B[idx], if idx >=0, and Bn[-idx] otherwise. I wanted the second one, but doesn't work well with templates unless I create two arrays in sequence and only use the second (for both positive and negative indices). For now, I'm using (3), but if there was some way to safely use (2) I'd like to know.

Comment: @user3225454 (4) Set a private const/constexpr static pointer on the template struct for the second half of the array. (5) Create an inline static member function that does the math for you. Both of these options should be inlined and folded by the compiler.

Comment: (4) would look exactly like option (3) when using the array, so it's more code without solving anything (also requires knowledge of MAXN, so another template argument is still required). (5) is just like (1) but with a method to make it look like (2); looks good, but still requires MAXN and an extra addition for every access (and I can create that method for any of the alternatives actually). I mean, if I really need to pass an extra parameter, it seems simpler to just pass Bn instead of MAXN. This whole discussion is so I can just find a solution to pass only 2 (instead of 3) template args.

Comment: Actually, (4) could look like (2), I failed to see that. Still, requires MAXN =/

Comment: @user3225454 I have a potential solution, but note that there is no extra addition on every access anyway -- these are all compile time constants, so the compiler will fold the extra addition at compile time.

Comment: Oh right. Still, my main complaint is I still need a third template arg anyway. I'm very curious about your potential solution though!

Comment: @user3225454 Is one array acceptable though? Is it always true that the array is divided into two equal pieces, each of which you need a pointer to the start?

Comment: One array is acceptable, and even better than having two! It has size 2*MAXN, and I only need a pointer to the middle (MAXN), since I need to access indices (MAXN + x), where -MAXN < x < MAXN.